# Error while deploying Symfony2 project with capifony

Tags: deployment, symfony, debian, capifony

I want to deploy my newly build Symfony2 project using capifony. After the initial setup with `cap deploy:setup`, which worked just fine, all the needed files/folders were created.

But now when I want to `cap deploy` the subdirectories aren't created.

Comment: An error message, or output, or something would be cool.

Comment: Well, it just fails to install the vendors since the subdirectories are missing.     `failed: "sh -c 'cd /var/www/project/releases/20120402201938 && php bin/vendors install --reinstall'" on host.com`

Comment: Mhm, just noticed that in the latest version of symfony there is no  `php bin/vendors` and after a reboot the subdirectories got created. I have no idea..

Comment: The latest version of Symfony2 uses composer to manage vendor libraries.

Comment: At least capifony from master-branch supports composer as well https://github.com/everzet/capifony/issues/100

Answer (score 1):

I guess you use a Symfony2 version that relies on Composer to manage dependencies.
In capifony 2.1.7 (last release), you can decide to use Composer to setup your vendors:

```
set :use_composer, true
```